# Get return value of fputcsv

Tags: php, csv

Does anyone know of a function, or a cool trick, to get the return value of `fputcsv` instead of writing the output to file?

I'm trying to encode a file as a tab-delimited file, but my client wants one of the columns encoded in csv (so 1 column of csv values in a tab delimited file).  Not ideal, I agree, but at this point I just need to get it done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shamelessly copying from a [user note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#105110) on the documentation page:

```
$buffer = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
fputcsv($buffer, $data);
rewind($buffer);
$csv = fgets($buffer);
fclose($buffer);

// Perform any data massaging you want here
echo $csv;
```

All of this should look familiar, except maybe [`php://temp`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Comment: Accepted this answer because it's more complete. works great! good thing to note though, make sure you `trim` after the `fgets` to get rid of the new line that `fputcsv` adds!

Comment: Note: `fgets($buffer)` will get only 1 line - consider using `stream_get_contents($buffer)` instead

Answer (score 3):

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, $line);
fclose($output);
```

Or try one of the other [supported wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php), like `php://memory` if you don't want to output directly.